# ProgressBar With Percentage In Label.Text In Foreach

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, progress-bar

I have this code and I have a ProgressBar, I want to write percentage of my progressBar in a label. How can I do this in foreach loop? It's my code:

```
       prg.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
       con.Open();
       //insignificant sql and listbox operations...
       prg.Value = 0;
       prg.Maximum = myDataTable.Rows.Count;
       foreach (DataRow myRows5 in myDataTable.Rows)
       {
           dgv.Rows.Add(...);
           prg.Value++;
           Application.DoEvents();
           lbl.Text = "Loading... %" + Convert.ToString("I will put here of percentage...");
       }
```

Note: Percentage formale will be int percent = ((prg.Value / prg.Maximum) * 100)

Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display the percentage like so:

```
lbl.Text = string.Format("Loading... {0:p0}", (prg.Value / (double)prg.Maximum));
```

The `p0` formatter will convert a value between 0 and 1 to a percentage with 0 decimal places.

If you actually need the percentage for other calculations, you can calculate it almost as you described:

```
int percent = (int)(prg.Value / (double)prg.Maximum);
```

Note the conversion of one of the values to `double` to ensure that integer division isn't used.